# Testing in-app billing in Android - Received empty signature

Tags: android, billing

I am following the tutorial on this [link](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/simple-inapp-billing-payment/) to implement in-app billing in Android. I tried it on my Galaxy S and everything worked correctly. I got the right answers, including signature.

However, when I migrate it to my app (same code with my own public key) I receive all the responses with no signature at all. I am sure that the key is correctly copied, and I have also tried exporting the app using the Eclipse wizard and uploaded it as a draft to the Play Store.

Does anybody have any clue why this might happen? The only two possible reasons I have found searching are using a wrong public key and not uploading the app as a draft, and thus far none of them solve my problem.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual, refer to the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/index.html) and sample app source code for best results.

I haven't seen this, but after you upload as draft you need to wait for a while for the app to become active (about  an hour last time I tested). A wrong public key has nothing to do with an empty signature: responses are signed by the Play Store servers with your *private* key, you only need to verify them with the public key. So this is either a glitch with the Play Store (less likely) or you are missing something in your app.

Comment: Well, the application now works correctly. I uploaded its draft version to the PlayStore, but did not activate it...I don't know if it has something to do with the waiting that Nikolay mentions...

The other thing that might have affected is the fact that I set my gmail account as the address for the developer account, whereas I previously had it as a test account.